# Is there a memory leak in this D example?

Tags: memory-leaks, d

From the offical D book:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    double[] slice1 = [ 1, 1, 1 ];
    double[] slice2 = [ 2, 2, 2 ];
    double[] slice3 = [ 3, 3, 3 ];

    slice2 = slice1;      // ← slice2 starts providing access
                          //   to the same elements that
                          //   slice1 provides access to

    slice3[] = slice1;    // ← the values of the elements of
                          //   slice3 change

    writeln("slice1 before: ", slice1);
    writeln("slice2 before: ", slice2);
    writeln("slice3 before: ", slice3);

    slice2[0] = 42;       // ← the value of an element that
                          //   it shares with slice1 changes

    slice3[0] = 43;       // ← the value of an element that
                          //   only it provides access to
                          //   changes

    writeln("slice1 after : ", slice1);
    writeln("slice2 after : ", slice2);
    writeln("slice3 after : ", slice3);
}
```

slice2 is pointing to some data, then changed to point to something else, isn't this going to cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 8):

D is a garbage collected language. The garbage collector will likely eventually free memory allocated for unreachable objects.

Comment: And in case of memory being allocated statically, it won't be freed by the GC. But the compiler could be smart enough to drop the initial allocation for `slice2`, and have that variable point to `slice1` directly, since `slice2 = slice1;` is directly following the variable definitions.